# Asia and Europe tags. Why?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by the recent question [Is it a good salary negotiation tactic to say, "Make me an offer and I will either accept it or walk away"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/188283/is-it-a-good-salary-negotiation-tactic-to-say-make-me-an-offer-and-i-will-eith)

I think that the Europe and Asia tags should be deleted.
They're the only continents which have their own tags, and the tags don't appear to serve any useful purpose.

Does something which applies to the UK also apply to Portugal? Does something which applies to Japan also apply to Korea?
Of course not, so why do those tags exist?

Country tags are more appropriate and should be used instead of continent tags.

Comment: *"Does something which applies to the UK also apply to Portugal? Does something which applies to Japan also apply to Korea?
Of course not [...]"* - Citation Needed

Comment: @DarkCygnus Do we really need a citation for the obvious fact that North Korea/China and Japan/Israel have very little in common? Technically, all are "Asia" on the continent scale. If you ask me to find a common denominator I would say "attacking your boss with a chainsaw will get you in trouble." Probably true for all. But if it goes into any more detail, I'm pretty sure they are different.

Comment: Having looked at the tags, I will go ahead and remove continent tags from questions that are *already country tagged*. They make zero sense there. Having something tagged [India][Asia] is pointless. It's not like we have another additional secret India tucked away somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

Geographical tags that are not countries do not help in any way.

I'm sure laws, norms and workplaces differ *a lot* between Israel, Saudi-Arabia, India, China, Japan, Indonesia and North Korea. It's all Asia though.

And while Europe is a little smaller, I'm pretty sure a solution good for Spain is not applicable in Belarus.

And while we are at it... what exactly *are* Turkey and Russia? Asia or Europe?

So... those tags are not helpful. There is no expert in "Asia" workplaces. Or "Europe" workplaces.

From my point of view they should be removed and replaced by country tags. Or maybe tags of juristiction or other regions that law applies to if of interest for the question (maybe European Union, Schengen Area etc). Those are really helpful in finding or answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question - I disagree with the conclusion but I think that it is worth discussing.

In the question mentioned, what was asked hinged *heavily* on cultural norms. How to negotiate a salary is something where there is still a great deal of discrepancy in how it's handled.

However - there are other Workplace issues that are less influenced by Culture and more to do with Law and Regulation - as such, the EU and ECJ (European Union and European Court of Justice) are most likely applicable. Even non EU countries, such as the UK (heh) have a fair degree of overlap in terms of Workers rights and protections.

As such, a Europe tag is appropriate IMO when used in the correct context.

I'm not familiar enough with Asia to give an equivalent answer - but I suspect that there are indeed some cross-overs in the Asian region (especially those that share a landmass - such as South East Asia) that such a tag, when used in the right context is applicable.

In a more broader sense, most of what is asked here is applicable to Corporate life - which for the most parts means it's heavily focused on the USA, Europe and Asia. And since everyone knows that on the internet the default is the USA (I jest...) - then having the tags to essentially say 'Not the USA' has merit.

I do, however, agree that having country tags is perhaps something that should be considered. The only pause I have for saying this is that restricting people to use Country tags may inhibit a user from asking a question, especially if it's a niche field or question and disclosing a country could make it identifiable.

Comment: Asia is a LOT less homogeneous than Europe (which is only homogeneous in very broad strokes). Tag is a waste of effort.